# Is a virtual function with a prototype that doesn't depend on template parameters valid in a template?

Tags: c++, templates

Given the following code:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
public:
  virtual void Foo() {};
  virtual void Bar(const T& t) {};
};
```

I know that virtual functions such as `Bar` above are not allowed since templates are generated during compile-time and virtual functions uses the virtual table, which occurs during run-time which means that there's no finite number of signatures for that virtual function that can satisfy the virtual table.

But if the function has a signature that does not depend on `T`, such as `Foo` above, will that still be illegal?

Comment: As stated below, you can use virtual functions - but do you really need one in your template?

Comment: @DieterLücking That was and educational question, not a practical one.

Comment: Contrary to your assumption that my dowvote was pathological, I have probably spent more time trying to find an appropriate way to edit this question so that it is clear to future readers than you bothered to spend posting it in the first place.  Take a look and make sure the spirit of the question is still intact.

Comment: Next time, don't assume that I'm downvoting you just because I have to downvote *someone*.  If I'm spending this much time and energy on someone else's question, there might be a reason other than to just make you a victim.

Comment: @JohnDibling, considering the fact the the virtual function is allowed, you've shrieked it perfectly. The intention in the original code was to show that even though the `print` was not using any of the template's parameters, the overloading of ostream operator did. But that's irrelevant now. Please take a snap look at your comments and try to understand where what I wrote came from.

Comment: A key part of the original question was your presumption that `virtual`s were not allowed if they took a dependent parameter, so I wanted to preserve that.  So are you saying this edit is ok?

Comment: @JohnDibling this edit is perfect. Thank you for your time and patience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I know that virtual functions are not allowed inside templates

No, you don't. It's perfectly possible for *class* templates to have virtual member functions - all classes instantiated from that template will have a set and finite number of virtual functions. A *member function* template can't be virtual - that would mean (potentially) infinitely many virtual functions.

So in your case, having a virtual non-template member function is just fine. It would be just as fine even if the signature did depend on `T`.

Comment: I should `#define KNOW THINK_I_KNOW`

Comment: Lets go on to say that class templates can override virtual functions in their parent classes. However, remember that A<T>!=A<J> in *any way*, even if their interfaces are exactly the same.

Comment: -1:  You didn't answer the actual question.  Downvote is just to get your attention.

Comment: @JohnDibling Care to explain how I didn't answer it? The only question I see is "Will that (still) be illegal?" My answer says "you're perfectly fine, and you'd even be with a dependent signature." How does this *not* answer the question?

Comment: @JohnDibling, I think that in the last sentence of the answer, answers the question directly.

Comment: The question appears to be asking if `const` member functions are legal in a class template.  All the `virtual` stuff was just preamble.

Comment: @JohnDibling I disagree. To me, the OP seems to mean "constant" as in "doesn't depend on template parameters," not as `const`.

Comment: @JohnDibling, sorry for the misunderstanding, I didn't know how to phrase the fact that the virtual function's prototype is not using any template parameters (now I know).

Comment: @JohnDibling Come on. Is it really unclear enough to deserve a downvote? You could edit it instead.

Comment: @JohnDibling, I have edited the question, but feel free to keep that d/v there. You act as if d/ving satisfies you. You just HAD to d/v someone, if not Angew, then the question itself, ignoring my apologizing comment (apologizing for me being unclear or your misunderstanding). Oh, and if you don't know how to edit questions I think that with a reputation like yours it's about time to [RTFM](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Comment: @Quaker:  I know *how* to edit.  I was saying I wasn't sure how to edit your question to be clear & less confusing.  Apologizing is nice and fine and all, but it won't really help future readers.  The question needs to be clear.  And by the way I did read your edit.  It doesn't help much. I don't have a pathological need to downvote anyone.  Either Angew's answer was off-topic or your question was unclear.  It's as simple as that.